# Tango Developer Kit Purchase

Tags: google-project-tango

Can someone help me with this. I work at Foster&Partners Architecture as design system analyst, looking into ways to integrate new technologies into the architecture/design environment. We have requested a tango developer kit and got a response with a link to buy the kit. The link seems to be broken. Is there any way to buy the kit on the Google store or any other place.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem: Make sure you visit the site signed in to google wallet the google account that requested the kit, otherwise it will display as not available. I did see (but did not follow) alternate instructions which allow you to assign to an alternate email address the invitation to purchase.

If you received the invitation email, read the bottom where it mentions "whitelist".